# Does Hinduism permit kings to act tyrannical?

Tags: kings, governance

Does Hinduism permit kings to act tyrannical? As in allowing kings to exploit the people, loot them, kill, take women, etc?

Comment: Is that a genuine Q? Why will kings be allowed to do such things by the scriptures?

Comment: @Rickross Yes, and the reason is because there are many, many people who say that monarchical governments are *inherently* tyrannical, or that they permit tyranny and the citizens must obey. But that is not the case according to Hindu scripture, and so I provided the answer to dispel that misconception.

Comment: @AkshayS Yes, and the reason is because there are many, many people who say that monarchical governments are *inherently* tyrannical, or that they permit tyranny and the citizens must obey. But that is not the case according to Hindu scripture, and so I provided the answer to dispel that misconception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## No, Hinduism forbids kings from acting tyrannical.

Some verses from the *Manusmriti*:

> The king, who, without affording protection, takes tributes, taxes,
> duties, presents and fines, would immediately sink into hell.—(8.307)
>
> He who affords no protection and devours the people, grabbing his
> tribute of the sixth part of the produce,—him they declare to be the
> imbiber of the filth of the whole people.—(8.308)
>
> He who heeds not the bounds of morality, who is a disbeliever, who is
> extortionate, who does not afford protection, and is grabbing,—such a
> king one should regard as doomed to perdition.—(8.309)
>
> He who, on being abused by men in distress, forgives, becomes exalted
> to heaven, by that act; while he who, through kingly pride, does not
> forgive, goes, by that act, to hell.—(8.313)

So a king who is unrighteous and oppresses his people goes to hell.

Also, just like the US 2nd amendment, one can take up arms to defend himself and others, even against a tyrannical king, according to the Manusmriti:

> Twice-born persons shall carry arms: When religion is interfered with,
> when there is confusion among the twice-born castes caused by the
> exigencies of time,—(348) in his own defence, in cases of hindrance of
> sacrificial fees, in the case of outrages upon Brāhmaṇas and women,—if
> one strikes in the cause of right, he incurs no sin.—(8.348-8.349)

And Medhatithi's commentary for that verse:

> Another interpretation possible is that—“when religion is interfered
> with, when there is confusion caused by exigencies of time, i.e., when
> things have become unsettled on the death of a king—one may take up
> arms; but at other tiroes the necessary protection would be afforded
> by the king himself.”
>
> But in reality the king cannot spread out his hands and reach every
> individual person in the kingdom. There are some desperados who attack
> even the boldest, and the most trusted officers of the king; but they
> fear persons carrying arms.
>
> For these reasons it is right that one should carry arms at all times.
>
> ‘Caused by the exigencies of time,’—such as the death of the king, and
> such other calamities. On all these occasions one shall carry arms fur
> the protection of his properly and family.
>
> Others hold that on the occasions stated, arms may be carried for the
> sake of other people also;—says Gautama (21.19)—‘Also when some one is
> striking a weaker man, if he is able to rescue him.’

Additional commentary called *Madanapārijāta*:

> if there is interference with the sacred duties **due either to the
> tendencies of the king** or to the tendency of the times

And commentary called *Mitākṣarā*:

> when, on the waning of royal authority due to foreign invasion, one
> has to take care of himself

Answer (score 1):

No. Kings who act tyrannically will be destroyed.

**Unrighteous King**

> Vamadeva continued, ‘When the king, who is powerful, acts
>   unrighteously towards the weak, they who take their birth in his race
>   imitate the same conduct. Others, again, imitate that wretch who sets
>   sin agoing. Such imitation of the man ungoverned by restraints soon
>   begins destruction upon the kingdom. The conduct of a king who is
>   observant of his proper duties, is accepted by men in general as a
>   model for imitation. **The conduct, however, of a king who falls away
>   from his duties, is not tolerated by his very kinsfolk. That rash king
>   who, disregarding the injunctions laid down in the scriptures, acts
>   with high-handedness in his kingdom, very soon meets with
>   destruction.** That Kshatriya who does not follow the conduct observed
>   from days of old by other Kshatriyas conquered or unconquered, is said
>   to fall away from Kshatriya duties.’

*Mahabharata, Santi Parva, Section XCIII*

> When the Rishis were moreover insulted by the pretentious scholarship
>   of Vena, and when they found that their noble prayer for the welfare
>   of the world as a whole was rejected, their anger was aroused, and
>   they said: Let him be destroyed, let him perish. He is by nature a
>   perverted monster. To let him live is to allow the worlds to be
>   reduced to ashes. **An evil person like him deserves not to sit on the
>   throne.**

*Srimad Bhagavata Purana IV.14.30-32*

> The King derives his highest good by protecting his people. A King who
>   protects his people well, will derive one-sixth of the merits of his
>   subjects in the life hereafter. **But a King who collects taxes from
>   people without administering their affairs properly, will lose all the
>   merits to his credit and will inherit the sins of his people to boot.**

*Srimad Bhagavata Purana  iV.20.14*